# php json multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have some confusion about why the following code does not work:

```
$data_set = array();
for($i=1; $i<=3; $i++)
{
  $data_val = array($i, $i*2);
  $data_set[] = $data_val;
}

echo json_encode($data_set);
```

What I expect is something like

```
[ [1,2], [2,4], [3,6] ]
```

What I get is an empty string.

But, If I do this

```
$data_set = array();
for($i=1; $i<=3; $i++)
{
  $data_val = array($i, $i*2);
  $data_set[] = json_encode($data_val);
}

echo json_encode($data_set);
```

I get something like this:

```
[ "[1,2]", "[2,4]", "[3,6]" ]
```

So, it seems like deeper **Arrays** do not work.
What am I missing?

Comment: I tried running your first example and it gave me the expected result. i.e. `[[1,2],[2,4],[3,6]]`

Comment: Can you do `var_dump($data_set);` instead? Your code works: http://3v4l.org/AiL2U

Comment: Works perfectly for me.

Comment: Both Drumbeg and VikingBlooded are correct. Don't know where my confusion came from.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to convert the elements of the array, then convert the entire

```
$data_set = array();
for($i=1; $i<=3; $i++)
{
  $data_set[] = array($i, $i*2);
}

echo json_encode($data_set);
```